# How do I avoid being wiped out by facehuggers?

Tags: aliens-dark-descent

I recently started playing Aliens: Dark Descent, and I've gotten to the first queen fight. The mechanic that's causing me the most trouble is when she launches facehuggers at my squad. She tosses so many that my entire squad just gets covered in facehuggers, and then the whole squad just dies. I'm obviously doing something wrong, because right now facehuggers seem impossible to deal with.

**How do I deal with facehuggers? How can I  avoid a total squad wipe by facehuggers?**

Answer (score 2):

I managed to survive, and wipe out the enemy queen and its facehuggers. I even replayed it a few times to get a better grasp on some strategies.

The key thing is to **slow or pause time**. Opening the skill menu via `Spacebar` will either slow or pause time, depending on your settings. Facehuggers move *really* fast, so to have time to actually respond to them, you should make sure you leverage the skill menu to give you more time to respond.

Once you've slowed time, there's a few strategies you can try. First off, mark the facehuggers as priority targets (left mouse click them on PC). Marking the facehuggers as priority targets will cause your marines to focus fire them, which should make fairly short work of them. If you don't tell your marines to focus fire the facehuggers, they might just ignore them completely in favour of other threats, which will quickly lead to facehugging death.

Another strategy you should leverage a **Shotgun**, **flamethrower**, and **grenade launcher**. All of these skills will make fairly quick work of any facehuggers, *especially* when they're all grouped up.

So, in summary, when there's only 1 or 2 facehuggers, then marking them as priority targets should be sufficient to deal with them. For larger groups, then you should leverage your special skills, such as the shotgun, flamethrower, and grenade launcher. No matter what strategy you rely on, you should definitely go into slow mode as soon as you detect any facehuggers near by.

Comment: +1 Well made answer! The slow pause time method you mentioned is a great idea, never thought of it :D

Answer (score 1):

Some sources say to use a short blast of a flamethrower as they are vulnerable in they're early stages, or to burn the closed eggs to prevent them from spawning.

[Source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/751154-alien-isolation/70279132&ved=2ahUKEwjBspbM096AAxXDlWoFHRS_BhkQFnoECCcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0_3uSOAiXfyYmEhwVCUDwS)

[How to survive a face hugger attack](https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DjBGIzktktCs&ved=2ahUKEwjBspbM096AAxXDlWoFHRS_BhkQtwJ6BAghEAE&usg=AOvVaw21unjuqYHLQFNquQd-gYVx)